# Changing CyclesObjectSettings from a script and update the viewport

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I thought it was going to be an easy one for my first ever script but boy was I wrong.
All I wanted was a script that creates a basic plane and set it to be a Shadow Catcher so I wrote this basic code:

```
import bpy

# Create plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(
    size=10, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
shadow_catcher = bpy.context.active_object

# Set plane to be a shadow catcher
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
shadow_catcher.cycles.is_shadow_catcher = True
shadow_catcher.cycles_visibility.glossy = False
shadow_catcher.cycles_visibility.diffuse = False
shadow_catcher.cycles_visibility.transmission = False
shadow_catcher.cycles_visibility.scatter = False
```

This worked for creating the plane and setting the values but the results are not represented in the view port, It does work when rendering but I would like to be able to preview it. I've read about

```
bpy.context.scene.update()
```

and that it was later replaced by:

```
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

Since it is also mentioned in the Stale Data entry in the [API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#no-updates-after-setting-values) I've tried and implement a view layer update like so:

```
import bpy

# Create plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(
    size=10, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
shadow_catcher = bpy.context.active_object

# Set plane to be a shadow catcher
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
shadow_catcher.cycles.is_shadow_catcher = True
shadow_catcher.cycles_visibility.glossy = False
shadow_catcher.cycles_visibility.diffuse = False
shadow_catcher.cycles_visibility.transmission = False
shadow_catcher.cycles_visibility.scatter = False

# Update view layer
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

but I don't see any difference. I wonder whether I'm not implementing the update() function correctly or whether it's not the problem in the first place, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call [`Object.update_tag()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html?highlight=update_tag#bpy.types.ID.update_tag) to update the actual *display data*:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# Set the engine to cycles
C.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'

# Create the primitive
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=10)

# Get a reference to the primitive
shadow_catcher = C.active_object

# Set plane to be a shadow catcher
shadow_catcher.cycles.is_shadow_catcher = True

# Update tag call on the shadow catcher object
shadow_catcher.update_tag()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works has expected