# Cycles Camera Culling set by Python not triggering

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, visibility

I'm making a script to set the Cycles camera culling to True for all valid objects. The problem is although the object value changes (and the UI reflects that), it doesn't actually behave/cull (if I do a grab operator, "G", on the object can start culling afterward, even if the operation is cancelled). It only works immediately if I manually toggle the value.

My question is two-fold: one, why does it not work automatically (does it have to do with the non-Python code needing to be triggered)? Second, how to have any necessary triggering to be done via Python (the less hacky the better, but I'll settle if it's the only way)?

````py
import bpy

def valid_item(ob):
    return ob.type in {'MESH', 'CURVE', 'SURFACE', 'FONT', 'META', 'LIGHT', 'VOLUME', 'POINTCLOUD', 'HAIR'} or (
            ob.instance_type == 'COLLECTION' and ob.instance_collection)
            
            
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
cscene = scene.cycles
scene.render.use_simplify = True
cscene.use_camera_cull =  True

for o in scene.objects:
    if valid_item(o):
        o.cycles.use_camera_cull = True
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.update_tag()` updates the objects in 3d View: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html?highlight=update_tag#bpy.types.ID.update_tag

> Tag the ID to update its display data, e.g. when calling bpy.types.Scene.update

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.cycles.use_camera_cull = True
    obj.update_tag()
```

[Changing CyclesObjectSettings from a script and update the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237561/changing-cyclesobjectsettings-from-a-script-and-update-the-viewport/237564#237564)

Comment: It's always the little things - thank you!